# Pattern matching in regex in ruby or rails

Tags: regex, ruby

I am new to regex and looked into the possible matching expression. But I can't able to find the thing I needed. What I want is remove the word that matches certain expression. The expression is to match all the words ignoring whitespaces, tabs and newline. I am not able to find the correct regex in ruby.

For example:

```
string = 'hello world welcome'
```

The thing I need to do is to replace certain words matches with word starting with 'w' and end with 'd'.

```
string.gsub(/^w.*d$/, 'human')
```

but I am not able to ignore(escape) spaces(not replacing), tabs and new lines in that.

Can someone help with this. I tried with this below regexp to escape but its not happening.

```
string.gsub(/^w.*d$\s/, 'human')
```

`'hello world welcome'` must be changed to `'hello human welcome'` without removing spaces, tabs and newlines in the string.

Is that anywhere I can know more about regexp especially with ruby.

Comment: It appears you may want something like `string.gsub(/\b\w[a-z]*d\b/i, 'human') #=> "hello human welcome"`. You don't want either anchor. `^` would require `'world'` to be at the beginning of the line to be matched and hence replaced. Similarly, `$` would require `'world'` to be at the end of the line to be matched. The word boundaries, `\b` (aka "word breaks"). prevent a match if the string were `'Hello underworld welcome'` and `'Hello worldly welcome'`. `/i` makes the regex *case-indifferent*, so it will match, say, `'World'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understand your question the regular expression would be:

```
\bw[a-z]*d
```

See [the pattern in action](http://regexr.com/56m77) on Regexr, which helps generate regular expressions and tells you exactly what you are doing.

Cary Swoveland's response is also good.

Comment: Thanks:). But why it doesn't work for special characters while I tired \b{[a-z]*} it doesn't work. And also I tried escaping characters \b\{[a-z]*\}

Comment: @hello: Don't try to change your question in comments. Please, edit your question and add real test cases with exected result.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It is just going to select a different range of words. `\{` is an escaped character, meaning that it is going to look for characters that start with "{". But if you want your RegEx to actually capture words withing the curly braces then `\{[a-z]*\}`. You can also take a look at this `\{\bw|W[a-zA-Z]*d|D\}`.

Comment: You can use the resources left by Todd A. Jacobs to further your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Your regex has many problems, including:

1. being improperly anchored to the beginning and end of the line
2. using greedy matchers
3. using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) instead of [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-sub) when you only want to replace only the first match

You can learn more about Ruby's regex engine and expressions in the documentation for the [Regexp class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html). O'Reilly also publishes [many books](https://smile.amazon.com/s?k=o%27reilly%20regular%20expressions) about regular expressions, and the different features found in several popular languages and regular expression engines/implementations.

### Solution

There's more than one way to achieve your goal with this specific string. The following will work:

```rb
string = "hello world welcome"

# specify string instead of regex pattern
string.sub "world", "human"
#=> "hello human welcome"

# replacement using word boundaries
string.sub /\bworld\b/, "human"
#=> "hello human welcome"

# unanchored, non-greedy matching
string.sub /\bw.*?\b/, "human"
#=> "hello human welcome"
```

All examples yield the same results. The first example is likely best, as you already *know* what word you want to replace and can simply specify the string. The other examples leverage:

- `\b` as a zero-width assertion to anchor the string or pattern using word boundaries
- `*?` to define a non-greedy pattern that will match the *shortest* possible match

These solutions all work with your posted samples. Your mileage may vary with other inputs.